# Starting second javascript when the first one is finished

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a progress bar. It has a label. I want to adjust that label a certain script is finished. After finding some answers of probable solution, I came up with the following script. The first initiates and works as expected. However, the second one doesn't. What's wrong with it? Here's the code:

```
HTML:
<form method ="post">
    <input class=generate type="submit" value="Upload" onclick="move();finalize()"/>
</form>

Javascript:
<script>
function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
    var myFunc01 = function() {
    var i = 1;
    while (i < 101) {
        (function(i) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                i++; 
                elem.style.width = i + '%';
                elem.innerHTML = i + '%';
            }, 600 * i)
        })(i++)
    }
    };
    myFunc01();
}
</script>
<script>
function finalize() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
    var myFunc02 = function() {
                elem.innerHTML = 'Finalizing...';
    };
    setTimeout(myFunc02, 600);
}
</script>
```

Comment: The load order of scripts is unrelated to the logical order of function execution.  By the time the button is clicked everything has loaded already.  You should call finalize within the anonymous setTimeout function's last execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('#myBar');

function done() {
  elem.innerText = 'UPLOAD HAS FINISHED';
}

var upload = function(callback) {

  var width = 1;
  var id;

  var frame = function() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
      callback();
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  };

  id = setInterval(frame, 10);
};

/*
upload(function() {
  elem.innerText = 'UPLOAD HAS FINISHED';
});
*/
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 27px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="upload(done)">START UPLOAD</button>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a callback. A callback is a function that runs upon completion.

```
function move(callback) {
    //code you want to happen first
}
move(function(){
    //code you want to have happen after completion
})
```

thats the basic idea of how a simple callback works

Answer (score 0):

Thanks James, that's it!
After some re-arranging, this is what the second script looks like. And it works as expected.

```
<script>
function finalize() {setTimeout(function(){
var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
var myFunc02 = function() {
            elem.innerHTML = 'Finalizing...';
};
myFunc02();
}
, 600);}
</script>
```